# How can I add to the list of allowed file extensions in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

By default, WordPress doesn't allow files with `.dmg` or `.jar` extensions (for example) to be uploaded or validated. This causes problems, not only when using the media uploader but also when copying/pasting paths into plugins that use these rules to validate file names (such as WooCommerce downloadable products).

How can we add to these default file types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way to add to the default mime type / file extension list would be to use the [`mime_types` filter](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/2583c1e4ec68275926c27c57913ace6ee9e3ac36/wp-includes/functions.php#L2259). Note that there's a reason WordPress hasn't added some types to this list (hint: security); so be mindful when modifying this list:

```
/**
 * Add to list of allowed file extensions 
 * 
 * @param array $types Default allowed mime types
 */
function so_custom_mime_types( $types ) {
    // Add relevant extensions and types to the default array
    $types['jar'] = 'application/java-jar';
    $types['dmg'] = 'application/x-bzip2';  // This may be something different, depending on your .dmg

    return $types;
}
add_filter( 'mime_types', 'so_custom_mime_types' );
```

It's also important to note that WordPress [un-sets some extensions such as `.exe`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/2583c1e4ec68275926c27c57913ace6ee9e3ac36/wp-includes/functions.php#L2361) during the actual upload process...so you may need to hook into [`upload_mimes`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/upload_mimes) instead of `mime_types`, depending on your use case.